# Scroll into a RichTextBox using buttons c#

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I code two buttons for scrolling into a RichTextBox up and down ? What I try :

```
private void btnScrollTop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            if (rtbDefinitie.SelectionStart >= 30) {
                rtbDefinitie.SelectionStart -= 30;
                rtbDefinitie.ScrollToCaret();
            }
        }
private void btnScrollBottom_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            if (rtbDefinitie.SelectionStart <= 30) {
                rtbDefinitie.SelectionStart += 30;
                rtbDefinitie.ScrollToCaret();
            }
        }
```

But it's seems to get stuck after I press scroll down button twice. What I need to do ?

Comment: The problem is that the second click is registered as a double click.  I have no experience in how to avoid that.  Mayby it is easier to start a timer that runs while the button is pressed.

Comment: What does *get stuck* exactly mean? Please describe your problem in detail!

Comment: @Casperah: or register the same handler for the DoubleClick event.

Comment: @Pilgerstorfer Franz After I press the scroll down button twice then If I press it again nothing happen and after this if I press up button then the scroll down button work only once (it's scroll only one line).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second click seems to be interpreted as DoubleClick, so you could just register this event too and put the same code behind it (or replace the `30` by `60`)

EDIT:
If the Application stucks, because it's working and does not have the time to update the GUI, you could try to call `Application.DoEvents();` after every raised Clickevent:

```
private void btnScrollBottom_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            if (rtbDefinitie.SelectionStart <= rtbDefinitie.TextLength) {
                rtbDefinitie.SelectionStart += 30;
                rtbDefinitie.ScrollToCaret();
                Application.DoEvents();
            }
        }
```

Comment: After I press the scroll down button twice then when I press it again nothing happen.

Comment: I think this is because of the if-clause: (rtbDefinitie.Selectionstart <= 30). Scrolling down will only work twice that way. Try to replace the "30" in the if-clause by the text's length.